# Convert string array to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So, I have to take input in an array format from the user. So, I decided to go ahead with `textarea` approach. This is the input format:

```
[
  [
    'Row 1 - Cell 1',
    'Row 2 - Cell 2'
  ],
  [
    'Row 2 - Cell 1',
    'Row 2 - Cell 2',
    'Row 2 - Cell 3',
  ]
]
```

Now I have to use this data in the form of array and perform some manipulation. But after taking input, it becomes a string. I have already tried with `JSON.parse()`, but have been unable to extract the array.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strings in JSON use double quotes (and doesn't allow trailing commas as in `'Row 2 - Cell 3',`). If you get to choose the format, insist that the user enters correct JSON. (Although given the data you've shown, CSV would probably be a simpler format for users to deal with, and there are myriad options for parsing CSV in JavaScript.)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If the data in your question is the input, what is the expected output? Where is your attempt to convert it from input to output?

Comment: @JordanRunning thanks! It was trailing comma only that I was overlooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace all single-quotes with double-quotes to make it valid JSON, then use `JSON.parse()`

```
var textarea = `[
  [
    'Row 1 - Cell 1',
    'Row 2 - Cell 2'
  ],
  [
    'Row 2 - Cell 1',
    'Row 2 - Cell 2',
    'Row 2 - Cell 3'
  ]
]`;

var validJson = textarea.replace(/'/g, '"');

var arrayData = JSON.parse(validJson);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. As it turns out, it was because of the trailing comma.

Comment: Arbitrarily replacing all `'` characters with `"` is going to fail as soon as a user enters something with a single-quote inside double-quotes, e.g. `["This isn't going to work"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid Json, you you have to use " instead of ' also delete the  trailing comma